# Parse switch input value ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using a Switch input in ant design form. The Switch input only returns `true` or `false` (boolean value). However, I want the Switch return 1 or 2 in my form. How can I do that?

```
<Form.Item className="cold-input" name="on" valuePropName="checked">
                <Switch
                    checkedChildren="On"
                    unCheckedChildren="Off"
                />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the Switch input - do you mean that you want to show the numbers 1 or 2, like in the third example here, where they show 0 or 1?  https://ant.design/components/switch/

Comment: Yeah I mean that input. The UI show 1 or 2 but the value is still true or false. I need the value in the form to be 1 or 2

Comment: Can't you keep the value in state? So you have a state that is a number, and then in the Switch onChange function, you can do something like: setSwitchState(checked ? 1 : 0);

Comment: But then how can I map that state to the form state
I use the Switch input inside the form component: https://ant.design/components/form/

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up manipulating an example on Ant Designs website where they did something similar to what you want. The code below maps the value of the Switch checked state to a field on the Form. I have included a link to a codepen too, where you can see the value of the "on" being printed in the console. The link to the codepen is here: https://codepen.io/clawcastle/pen/YzGGmZQ

onChange function:

```
  onSelectedChange = (checked) => {
    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
      on: checked ? 1 : 0
    });
    console.log(this.formRef.current.getFieldValue("on"));
  }
```

The Switch component:

```
<Form.Item noStyle name="on">
    <Switch
    onChange={this.onSelectedChange}
    checkedChildren="On"
    unCheckedChildren="Off"
    />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Thanks, actually you have a quite good solution. I wonder if I set the initialValue: {on: 2} of the form to 2. How can I make the switch false?

Comment: I guess you could set the "checked" prop on the switch in a way like this: checked={this.formRef.current.getFieldValue("on") === 1}